# document.evaluate but for any node

Tags: javascript, dom

`document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.getElementsByTagName`, and several others can be called on other elements/nodes that are not `document` (e.g., `element.getElementsByTagName`). I read somewhere that `document.evaluate` also could be used like this, but when I try `element.evaluate` I get an error. Was what I read wrong?

Update #1: Passing a different `contextNode` is not the solution. The same nodes are returned as when it is set to `document` unless the XPath expression is changed to match it. Even if I did do that, which I don't want to for several reasons, this doesn't provide a way to call `evaluate` on nodes that separate from the DOM.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate), it looks like if you want to pass a context node, it should be the second argument?

Comment: Tmo, `document.evalute` is for xml. Are you using xml?

Comment: @CertainPerformance If `contextNode` is set to any descendant of `document`, then `document.evaluate` will still return the same results as when that same parameter is set to `document` unless `xpathExpression` is modified in a certain way. Changing `contextNode` also doesn't let me call `evaluate` on nodes outside of the DOM tree.

Comment: @ElectroxMortem I am not using XML. I do not need to be using XML in order to use `document.evaluate`. That function is part of the DOM specification.